# Can we merge 2 videos using Flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, red5, wowza

I have video interview web application in php. The Video chatting and recording saving to wowza server. Now i want to merge 2 videos in the wowza using flex, can we do that in flex? If it possible please give a tutorial or a link

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you want to concatenate the videos one after the other, or somehow have them merged to play together? FYI Wowza is a Java application, anything you were to do on the server would have to be done in Java, Flex runs in your client browser.

Comment: i want to concatenate videos

Comment: In which case you can save yourself a lot of effort by simply using a playlist configuration in your player to play one video immediately after the other.

Comment: Hi @codeghost! Nice point, but what if he wants to take advantage of client resources. Imagine 100 users merging this in the same time. You will need really strong server for that... On the other hand I am not completely sure that what @Elby wants it is possible in case he wants to have just one file.

Comment: Ok any other open source technologies supported Video merging ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily via ffmpeg. Read more [here](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files).

Posts on SO about similar topics:

- [Combining two video from ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567713/combining-two-video-from-ffmpeg)
- https://superuser.com/questions/556308/ffmpeg-concatenate-videos-have-multiple-audio-stream