# ffmpeg append video with different dimensions

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg, terminal, concatenation

I am cropping and adding subtitles to a video using the following:

`ffmpeg -i inputfile.mov -lavfi "crop=720:720:280:360,subtitles=subs.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontsize=18'" -crf 1 -c:a copy output.mov`

I have another video called **credits.mp4** which has the same dimensions as the output.mov (after cropping). Can I do this during the above process, or would I have to use something like *concat* afterwards?

Using bash in Terminal on a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mov -i credits.mp4 -lavfi "[0]crop=720:720:280:360,subtitles=subs.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontsize=18',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Because no info was provided about your inputs I made some assumptions:

- The attributes of both input files are the same as they are fed to concat. If not then perform additional filtering to conform them to a common set of parameters.
- `credits.mp4` has audio. If not, then add an audio file or use the [anullsrc filter as an input to create silent/dummy/filler audio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/) for proper concatenation.