# FFMPEG Take 1 second clips each video file from a directory of files, and until total playtime reached

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a music art video project for a song.

I have a directory that contains approximately 400 individual videos

- varying lengths (as short as 3 seconds and as long as 31 minutes)
- varying file types (mp4 and webm)
- varying resolutions/framerates/bitrates

The output video should consist of:

- 1 second chunks of each video
- in round-robin fashion
- until all videos are played fully or the output total video length reaches a certain limit (example, 20 minutes).
- Output video should be 1280×720 at 24fps, with no preference to bitrate.
- Videos that are larger should be scaled down and letterboxed (vertically or horizontally).
- Audio is not important at all. The video can be silent. I can overlay audio separately.

I do not want to loop short videos. In the example below, you can see that, for `top-left-view-take-1.mp4`, each 'clip' that's taken is incrementally further into the video. In other words, it shouldn't take the same 1 second clip from the beginning. The goal is to get further in to each individual video as the output video progresses.

**For example, say my directory contains files such as the following (and, for the example here, we'll say that this is all files in the directory):**

```
overhead-view-take-1.mp4 (3 seconds, for the sake of the question)
top-right-view-take-1.mp4 (3 seconds, for the sake of the question)
top-right-view-take-2.mp4 (5 seconds, for the sake of the question)
outside-kaleidoscope-1.mp4
yellow-kaleidoscope-1.mp4
red-kaleidoscope-1.mp4
brake-lights-slow-1.mp4
soft-city-lights.webm
```

Assume anything that isn't marked with a video duration is at least 5 seconds long.

**Based on the above files & times, here would be the order and time code of each clip during the first 30 seconds of the output video:**

Based on each video's total duration, the output video should include 1 second clips from all videos in the directory.

| Output time | Clip time | Clip file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00-00:01 | 00:00-00:01 | overhead-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:01-00:02 | 00:00-00:01 | top-right-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:02-00:03 | 00:00-00:01 | top-right-view-take-2.mp4 |
| 00:03-00:04 | 00:00-00:01 | outside-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:04-00:05 | 00:00-00:01 | yellow-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:05-00:06 | 00:00-00:01 | red-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:06-00:07 | 00:00-00:01 | brake-lights-slow-1.mp4 |
| 00:07-00:08 | 00:00-00:01 | soft-city-lights.webm |
| 00:08-00:09 | 00:01-00:02 | overhead-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:09-00:10 | 00:01-00:02 | top-right-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:10-00:11 | 00:01-00:02 | top-right-view-take-2.mp4 |
| 00:11-00:12 | 00:01-00:02 | outside-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:12-00:13 | 00:01-00:02 | yellow-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:13-00:14 | 00:01-00:02 | red-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:14-00:15 | 00:01-00:02 | brake-lights-slow-1.mp4 |
| 00:15-00:16 | 00:01-00:02 | soft-city-lights.webm |
| 00:16-00:17 | 00:02-00:03 | overhead-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:17-00:18 | 00:02-00:03 | top-right-view-take-1.mp4 |
| 00:18-00:19 | 00:02-00:03 | top-right-view-take-2.mp4 |
| 00:19-00:20 | 00:02-00:03 | outside-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:20-00:21 | 00:02-00:03 | yellow-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:21-00:22 | 00:02-00:03 | red-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:22-00:23 | 00:02-00:03 | brake-lights-slow-1.mp4 |
| 00:23-00:24 | 00:02-00:03 | soft-city-lights.webm |

Now, the output video should include 1 second clips only from videos that still have time remaining. The videos that don't have any time remaining, such as `overhead-view-take-1.mp4` and `top-right-view-take-1.mp4`, are not present here.

| Output time | Clip time | Clip file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:24-00:25 | 00:03-00:04 | top-right-view-take-2.mp4 |
| 00:25-00:26 | 00:03-00:04 | outside-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:26-00:27 | 00:03-00:04 | yellow-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:27-00:28 | 00:03-00:04 | red-kaleidoscope-1.mp4 |
| 00:28-00:29 | 00:03-00:04 | brake-lights-slow-1.mp4 |
| 00:29-00:30 | 00:03-00:04 | soft-city-lights.webm |

**What I've tried**

- I've read through the docs and cobbled together some code that produces output, but it only seems to work with images; I can't get the same thing to work with videos (specifically the incremental chunks).
- I've tried manipulating commands meant to `create a snapshot every x seconds/frames' but I've hit dead ends there.
- I've also started trying to create a text file to run the input from. That's the point where I thought it would make sense to ask here.

My main issue is picking off incremental chunks of individual videos, and playing those in sequence.

Thoughts?

**Environment details**
I have access to Win, Mac, and Linux machines. So, that environment isn't as important to me. Here's ffmpeg's output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-0york0~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libzimg --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Comment: You're asking for too much, but for the main issue see [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/) Refer to example #1, but add appropriate `-ss` (offset) and `-t` (duration) values before each input.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think breaking it down makes sense. The main part I get stuck with is splitting into chunks. Even given a directory of videos with same attributes, how do I incrementally split each video into same-duration chunks until that has been done to all videos? If I can do that process, exporting into a temp directory, I could then concat videos in that temp directory into the desired output.

Comment: No need to pre-chunk anything. It can all be done in one command. The splitting/chunking/clipping is done via `-ss` and `-t`. There is no feature in ffmpeg to automatically increment the desired clip times, so you'll have to use scripting if you want to automate the proper `-ss` and `-t` values. [Getting the duration of each input with `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) should be very helpful for this.