# FFMPEG script to merge multiple videos and a background image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have 30 clips which are different in aspect ratio(like some videos are 1080*1920(they are vertical) and some are 1280*720(horizontal aspect ratio videos). I want to merge all of them but also have a static background image that is of 1920x1080 aspect ratio. The video would be such that all the clips are concatenated but they have a background image(just like those tiktok compilation videos on youtube). Can someone please help me with this program?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right site for your request...

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Example using 3 videos. It can easily be expanded to 30 videos. I broke the command into multiple lines so you can see the syntax better. Make it one line before executing.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex 
"[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:720,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v0];
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:720,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v1];
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:720,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v2];
 [0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a0];
 [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a1];
 [2:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a2];
 [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vid][a];
 [3][vid]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

References:

- [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)
- [How to center overlay in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)
- [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/)