# Cannot merge VisualSampleEntry error while appending videos in MP4parser

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mp4parser, mobile-ffmpeg

I am creating four videos with ffmpeg and then i am appending them with MP4parser.
Details of four videos that i am creating with ffmpeg.

- 1,2 video : created using one image

```
[-loop, 1, -i, Count_1627453922.jpg, -s, 720x1280, -vf, format=yuv420p,fps=25,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=1, -t, 2, -preset, ultrafast, CountImageVideo_1627453922.mp4]
```

- 3,4 video: trimming 3 second video from an existing mp4 video

```
[-i, footages_5_1624263519549.mp4, -ss, 00:00:00, -to, 00:00:02, -s, 720x1280, -r, 25, -preset, ultrafast, One_1627453926.mp4]
```

Now i am trying to append all these videos with MP4Parser and getting below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot merge VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@f3f76444] and VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@e20a2ed0]
        at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.mergeStsds(AppendTrack.java:116)
        at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.<init>(AppendTrack.java:59)
```

I have done some debugging and found something that can help understand error better.
[Sample Description boxes of two videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUSS.png)

Two video tracks have different formats (MP4v & AVC1). I am new to ffmpeg and MP4parser so did not getting what i am doing wrong. Thanks! in advance.

Logs of all video creation ffmpeg command and error of mp4parser

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I: Input #0, png_pipe, from '1628829731.jpg':
I:   Duration: 
I: N/A
I: , bitrate: 
I: N/A
I:     Stream #0:0
I: : Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1280x592
I: , 
I: 25 fps, 
I: 25 tbr, 
I: 25 tbn, 
I: 25 tbc
I: Input #1, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
I:   Duration: 
I: N/A
I: , start: 
I: 0.000000
I: , bitrate: 
I: 705 kb/s
I:     Stream #1:0
I: : Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
W: Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (FootageVideo_1628829747.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
I: Stream mapping:
I:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
I:  (png (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
I:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1
I:  (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
I: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xbdf3a220] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
I: Output #0, mp4, to 'FootageVideo_1628829747.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     encoder         : 
I: Lavf58.48.100
I:     Stream #0:0
I: : Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x592, q=2-31, 200 kb/s
I: , 
I: 24 fps, 
I: 12288 tbn, 
I: 24 tbc
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 mpeg4
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: cpb: 
I: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 
I: vbv_delay: N/A
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I:     Stream #0:1
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 aac
I: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 20080(1054KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(2100KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 26MB/29MB, paused 4.477ms total 113.190ms
I: frame=    9 fps=0.0 q=13.8 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.34 bitrate=   1.0kbits/s speed=0.665x    
I: frame=   24 fps= 23 q=24.9 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.97 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.953x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   40 fps= 26 q=21.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=1.07x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   55 fps= 27 q=23.7 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.27 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
I: frame=   71 fps= 28 q=31.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate= 716.9kbits/s speed=1.13x    
I: frame=   72 fps= 27 q=31.0 Lsize=     307kB time=00:00:03.01 bitrate= 832.4kbits/s speed=1.14x    
I: video:303kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 
I: 1.018265%
I: [aac @ 0xbdf43c00] Qavg: 65536.000
I: Image to video: 0 : 674960272
I: [-loop, 1, -i, Count_1628829749.jpg, -f, lavfi, -i, anullsrc, -s, 1280x592, -vf, scale='if(gt(a,1280/592),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a1280/592),-1,592)',format=yuv420p,fps=24,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=1, -t, 2, -preset, ultrafast, CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4]
I: [-loop, 1, -i, Count_1628829749.jpg, -f, lavfi, -i, anullsrc, -s, 1280x592, -vf, scale='if(gt(a,1280/592),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a1280/592),-1,592)',format=yuv420p,fps=24,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=1, -t, 2, -preset, ultrafast, CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4]
I: Image to Video: [-loop, 1, -i, Count_1628829749.jpg, -f, lavfi, -i, anullsrc, -s, 1280x592, -vf, scale='if(gt(a,1280/592),1280,-1)':'if(gt(a1280/592),-1,592)',format=yuv420p,fps=24,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=1, -t, 2, -preset, ultrafast, CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4]
I: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I: Input #0, png_pipe, from 'Count_1628829749.jpg':
I:   Duration: 
I: N/A
I: , bitrate: 
I: N/A
I:     Stream #0:0
I: : Video: png, rgba(pc), 1794x1080
I: , 
I: 25 fps, 
I: 25 tbr, 
I: 25 tbn, 
I: 25 tbc
I: Input #1, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
I:   Duration: 
I: N/A
I: , start: 
I: 0.000000
I: , bitrate: 
I: 705 kb/s
I:     Stream #1:0
I: : Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
W: Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
I: Stream mapping:
I:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
I:  (png (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
I:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1
I:  (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
I: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xbe554440] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
I: Output #0, mp4, to 'CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     encoder         : 
I: Lavf58.48.100
I:     Stream #0:0
I: : Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x592, q=2-31, 200 kb/s
I: , 
I: 24 fps, 
I: 12288 tbn, 
I: 24 tbc
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 mpeg4
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: cpb: 
I: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 
I: vbv_delay: N/A
I:     Stream #0:1
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 aac
W: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 1243219441 , only wrote 1243083210
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.09 bitrate=   3.8kbits/s speed=0.289x    
I: frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s speed=0.521x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   18 fps= 13 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.71 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=0.532x    
I: frame=   26 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.571x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   35 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=0.595x    
I: frame=   43 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=0.593x    
D: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.wallet.service.BIND pkg=com.google.android.gms }
D: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.mdd.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService }
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   48 fps= 14 q=2.0 Lsize=      75kB time=00:00:02.02 bitrate= 303.7kbits/s speed=0.586x    
I: video:72kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 
I: 3.472700%
I: [aac @ 0xbdf69c00] Qavg: 65536.000
I: Count Image to video: 0 : 674963874
I: Start Video Query: [-i, iOS_footages_4_1627755471638.mp4, -ss, 00:00:02, -to, 00:00:05, -s, 1280x592, -r, 24, -preset, ultrafast, TilePartOne_1628829753.mp4]
I: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'iOS_footages_4_1627755471638.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     major_brand     : 
I: qt  
I:     minor_version   : 
I: 0
I:     compatible_brands: 
I: qt  
I:     creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:     com.apple.quicktime.author: 
I: ReplayKitRecording
I:   Duration: 
I: 00:03:34.00
I: , start: 
I: 0.000000
I: , bitrate: 
I: 2183 kb/s
I:     Stream #0:0
I: (und)
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 37 kb/s
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Audio
I:     Stream #0:1
I: (und)
I: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 592x1280, 2139 kb/s
I: , 
I: 38.89 fps, 
I: 59.94 tbr, 
I: 600 tbn, 
I: 1200 tbc
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       rotate          : 
I: 270
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Video
I:       encoder         : 
I: H.264
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
W: Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (TilePartOne_1628829753.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
I: Stream mapping:
I:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0
I:  (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
I:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1
I:  (aac (native) -> aac (native))
I: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
W: [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0xedd7fca0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W: [swscaler @ 0xb645a800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: Couldn't load memtrack module
W: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
I: Output #0, mp4, to 'TilePartOne_1628829753.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     major_brand     : 
I: qt  
I:     minor_version   : 
I: 0
I:     compatible_brands: 
I: qt  
I:     com.apple.quicktime.author: 
I: ReplayKitRecording
I:     encoder         : 
I: Lavf58.48.100
I:     Stream #0:0
I: (und)
I: : Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x592, q=2-31, 200 kb/s
I: , 
I: 24 fps, 
I: 12288 tbn, 
I: 24 tbc
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 mpeg4
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Video
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: cpb: 
I: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 
I: vbv_delay: N/A
I:       
I: displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
I:     Stream #0:1
I: (und)
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Audio
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 aac
I: frame=    6 fps=6.0 q=5.8 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=   1.7kbits/s speed=0.208x    
I: frame=   28 fps= 18 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.736x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   44 fps= 22 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.79 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=15 speed=0.881x    
I: frame=   63 fps= 25 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.58 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=18 speed=1.01x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   72 fps= 24 q=31.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate= 709.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=0.968x    
I: frame=   72 fps= 21 q=31.0 Lsize=     448kB time=00:00:03.01 bitrate=1215.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=0.873x    
I: video:398kB audio:47kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 
I: 0.696200%
I: Start video: 0 : 674967468
I: [aac @ 0xb8c6e400] Qavg: 667.684
I: End Video Query: [-i, iOS_footages_4_1627755471638.mp4, -ss, 00:00:05, -to, 00:00:08, -s, 1280x592, -r, 24, -preset, ultrafast, TilePartTwo_1628829756.mp4]
I: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'iOS_footages_4_1627755471638.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     major_brand     : 
I: qt  
I:     minor_version   : 
I: 0
I:     compatible_brands: 
I: qt  
I:     creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:     com.apple.quicktime.author: 
I: ReplayKitRecording
I:   Duration: 
I: 00:03:34.00
I: , start: 
I: 0.000000
I: , bitrate: 
I: 2183 kb/s
I:     Stream #0:0
I: (und)
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 37 kb/s
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Audio
I:     Stream #0:1
I: (und)
I: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 592x1280, 2139 kb/s
I: , 
I: 38.89 fps, 
I: 59.94 tbr, 
I: 600 tbn, 
I: 1200 tbc
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       rotate          : 
I: 270
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Video
I:       encoder         : 
I: H.264
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
W: Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (TilePartTwo_1628829756.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
I: Stream mapping:
I:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0
I:  (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
I:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1
I:  (aac (native) -> aac (native))
I: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W: [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0xe2c97860] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W: [swscaler @ 0xb5d28a80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
I: Output #0, mp4, to 'TilePartTwo_1628829756.mp4':
I:   Metadata:
I:     major_brand     : 
I: qt  
I:     minor_version   : 
I: 0
I:     compatible_brands: 
I: qt  
I:     com.apple.quicktime.author: 
I: ReplayKitRecording
I:     encoder         : 
I: Lavf58.48.100
I:     Stream #0:0
I: (und)
I: : Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x592, q=2-31, 200 kb/s
I: , 
I: 24 fps, 
I: 12288 tbn, 
I: 24 tbc
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 mpeg4
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Video
I:     Side data:
I:       
I: cpb: 
I: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 
I: vbv_delay: N/A
I:       
I: displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
I:     Stream #0:1
I: (und)
I: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
I:  (default)
I:     Metadata:
I:       creation_time   : 
I: 2021-07-31T18:17:18.000000Z
I:       handler_name    : 
I: Core Media Audio
I:       encoder         : 
I: Lavc58.96.100 aac
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
I: frame=   10 fps=4.9 q=18.5 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.37 bitrate=   0.9kbits/s speed=0.183x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   31 fps= 12 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=0.491x    
I: frame=   52 fps= 17 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.12 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.692x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   72 fps= 20 q=31.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.827x    
I: frame=   72 fps= 18 q=31.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate= 709.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.725x    
E: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
E: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
I: frame=   72 fps= 16 q=31.0 Lsize=     543kB time=00:00:03.01 bitrate=1472.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.689x    
I: video:493kB audio:47kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 
I: 0.573798%
I: [aac @ 0xc2f20000] Qavg: 669.561
I: Movie paths: [CountImageVideo_1628829749.mp4, TilePartTwo_1628829756.mp4, FootageVideo_1628829747.mp4]
    
    --------- beginning of crash
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
    Process: com.wev.app, PID: 21310
    java.io.IOException: Cannot merge VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@ed48a2a8] and VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@dc387090]
        at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.mergeStsds(AppendTrack.java:116)
        at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.<init>(AppendTrack.java:59)
        at Mp4Cutter2.combineClips(Mp4Cutter2.kt:208)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity.finalVideoGenerate(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3457)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity.endVideoCreate(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3383)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity.startVideoCreate(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3298)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity.countImageToVideo(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3220)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity.imageToVideo(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3158)
        at com.wev.app.ui.activity.videoplayer.PlayVideoActivity$createWev$1$getVideo$imageToVideo$1.run(PlayVideoActivity.kt:3056)
```

Comment: You are outputting MPEG-4 Part 2 video. This is a legacy format. Are you sure MP4Parser supports that?

Comment: @IIogan What should be the outputting format for get videos merged with MP4Parser.

Comment: H.264. But your ffmpeg does not appear to have any H.264 encoder enabled. Alternative is to use the concat filter in ffmpeg. See [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/) for many examples.