# ffmpeg save output to a python variable and do further ffmpeg operations without writing multiple files

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, subprocess

I want to convert a gif to a video with ffmpeg in python and add sound to the video. Afterwards I want to merge the video with another video. I'm able to run the shell codes with `os.system()` in python, however I would like to avoid writing multiple files during my steps.

Is there a way to save the ffmpeg output in a variable and work with the variable instead of writing multiple files for each step? I want only to write my final file which should be a merged video file, containing the video and the sound from video1 and another video2. I've found some ways like the `subprocess` library, but unfortunately was not able to code my desired output.

Here is the code I use and which works for converting a gif to mp4 and add sound. But as described I need to write 2 different files.

GIF to video:

```
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {PATH_TO_GIF} -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video.mp4')
```

Add sound to video:

```
os.system(f"ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i {PATH_TO_SOUNDFILE} -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest video_with_sound.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
ffmpeg -i i.gif -i 1.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -shortest vid.mp4
```

Or maybe somehow possible with a two-pass conversion and dev null. As a last resort, it is always possible to execute several commands at once and remove unnecessary‍♂️

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also had this in my mind but was curious if there is a more efficient way without writing multiple files and deleting the unnecessary ones afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {PATH_TO_GIF} -i {PATH_TO_SOUNDFILE} -map 0:v -map 1:a -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart -shortest video_with_sound.mp4')
```

Optional: You can add `-c:a copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio if `{PATH_TO_SOUNDFILE}` is MP4/M4A/AAC.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. At the end I want to merge the video_with_sound.mp4 with another video2.mp4 to generate my final output. Is there a way to do so before writing the video_with_sound.mp4?

Comment: @rtn17 "merge" is ambiguous. Do you mean to concatenate where one video plays right after the other?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant with merge.

Comment: @rtn17 See [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)