# How can I concatenate 2 videos with audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

But `output.mp4` has no audio.

`mylist.txt` contains:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

Information about `1.mp4` and `2.mp4`:

```
C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder>ffmpeg -n -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-23-26b4509 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 48.100 / 56. 48.100
  libavcodec     58. 87.101 / 58. 87.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 83.100 /  7. 83.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2020-05-31T08:12:56.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:05.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 186 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 184 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-05-31T08:21:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2020-06-01T03:32:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1909 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1708 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-01T04:17:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-01T04:17:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Run this command: `ffmpeg -n -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4`. It will provide useful info about the inputs and your `ffmpeg` version. This info is required to provide an answer that you can copy and paste. Copy the **complete** log from that command. [Edit] your question and paste the complete log into your question. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified error` in the log.

Comment: Unfortunately you provided the log for the wrong command. I am looking for information about each of the inputs referenced in `mylist.txt`. For proper concatenation all inputs must have the same attributes. I wanted to check the inputs to see if their attributes match.

Comment: Again, that's the wrong command and the screenshots are not informative. Please run the exact command I suggested (`ffmpeg -n -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4`). This command is only to provide info: it is not meant for converting anything. You do not need to modify it. The log is text so copy and paste it instead of making screenshots of text. Screenshots of text are less helpful and are harder to use.

Comment: the log added for this command `ffmpeg -n -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

## For concatenation to work:

According to the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

- Each input must have the same number of video and audio streams.
- Each video and audio stream must have the same attributes.
- Each input must have the same video and audio format.

## What is wrong with your inputs

`1.mp4` has **no** audio. `2.mp4` has audio.

`1.mp4` needs audio to be able to concatenate to `2.mp4`.

## Solution

Add silent audio to `1.mp4` using [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest 1b.mp4
```

Then update `mylist.txt` to:

```
file '1b.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

Finally run your `ffmpeg` command to concatenate:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: thank-you for the solution. when running this command `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4` 2 hour video shrunked to 5 minutes

Comment: @EasyTricksForAndroid You must be using different inputs than shown in your question. This answer was specific to those two inputs. There must be some attribute that differs between the new files.

Comment: is it support different codec (h264 & h265) and different extension (.mp4 & .mkv).

Comment: @EasyTricksForAndroid Each input must have the same video and audio format. It seems like you are looking for a generic answer, and not an answer that works for the particular inputs you provided.