# ffmpeg concat image with video, but output extra long

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal: To concat an image (foo.jpg) with a video (bar.mp4, 3 seconds long). Show foo.jpg for 2 seconds only. Output video should be just around 5 seconds long.

I used:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -framerate 1 -i foo.jpg -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -i bar.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2:v][2:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [vpre][a];[vpre]fps=24,scale=32:24[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

I think the command means:
Loop foo.jpg for 2 seconds at framerate of 1 frame per second. At the same time, add silent audio track to the 2-second foo.jpg video.
Then concat with bar.mp4.
Make final output framerate 24 fps. Scale it to 32x24 dimension (intentionally tiny for testing).

Expected: output to be about 5 seconds long in total.

Reality: output is 3 minutes and 38 seconds long. The first 5 seconds is perfect. After that, video just stays silent with the 5th-second frame frozen until the end.

My research shows that it might be related to `-video_track_timescale`

This command also fails with same over-long result (I added `-video_track_timescale 600`):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -framerate 1 -i foo.jpg  -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -i bar.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2:v][2:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [vpre][a];[vpre]fps=24,scale=32:24[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -video_track_timescale 600 out.mp4
```

Additional info about file `bar.mp4`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i bar.mp4 
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bar.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 641 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/unknown/smpte170m), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 354 kb/s, 24.58 fps, 24.58 tbr, 113734695.00 tbn, 49.16 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 280 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: @llogan, please see the requested output in my post now.

Answer (score 0):

Same command, only added `-r 24` flag before my input video. This specifies my framerate so ffmpeg does not need to guess. Now when 2-second video concats with 3-second video, I get 5-second output.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -framerate 1 -i foo.jpg -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -r 24 -i bar.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2:v][2:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [vpre][a];[vpre]fps=24,scale=32:24[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

## concat demuxer

Using the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) preserves the quality of the main video, but is more complicated.

1. Make video from image, matching the attributes of the main video to concatenate to:

   ```
   ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24.58 -t 2 -i image.jpg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000 -vf "scale=480:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:360:-1:-1:color=black,format=yuv420p,setsar=1" -shortest image.mp4
   ```
2. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'image.mp4'
   file 'main.mp4'
   ```
3. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

## concat filter

The [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) lets you do everything in one command but re-encodes the main video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 2 -i image.jpg -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000 -i main.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=480:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:360:-1:-1:color=black,format=yuv420p,setsar=1[img];[2:v]fps=24[main];[img][1:a][main][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```