# Batch concatenate pairs of videos

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a directory with 1000+ video files. I'd like to concatenate them two-by-two.

An alphabetical ordering of the files give the desired pairs, e.g., the input files

```
 filename_1.mp4
 filename_2.mp4
 filename_3.mp4
 filename_4.mp4
 ...
```

should result in output files

```
 filename_1-2.mp4
 filename_3-4.mp4
 ...
```

They input files all have the same dimensions and formats.

How can I write a batch script invoking `ffmpeg` to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I took the liberty to re-write the question in a more compact and comprehensible form. Just a question: with those file names, wouldn't an alphabetical sort give you wrong pairs unless you left-pad the numbers by `0`'s, e.g. `filename_0001.mp4` etc.?

Comment: Based upon the fact that you're intending to do this with `.mp4` files, I'd strongly advise that you first read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7567713/6738015), and its answers.

Comment: Examples of code you've tried are always good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV3QgDq2TGw

Comment: @Carl Your edit adds some confusion. "merge videos two-by-two" made me assume the question is about a [2x2 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/). A better title would be something like "batch concatenate pairs of videos".

Comment: @llogan absolutely agree, title edited to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to loop through all of the files, and perform a simple binary switch either capturing the filename, or operating on the previously captured filename and the current file:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set _last=

for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    if "!_last!" == "" (
        set _last=%%a
    ) else (
        echo merging "!_last!" and "%%a" to "%%a_combined.mp4"
        echo file '!_last!'>simple_list.txt
        echo file '%%a'>>simple_list.txt
        rem Obviously, change this depending on how you want to invoke ffmpeg
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i simple_list.txt -c copy "%%a_combined.mp4"
        del simple_list.txt

        set _last=
    )
)

if not "!_last!" == "" (
    echo !_last! was unprocessed!
)
```

While this works, I'd highly recommend you consider approaching this task with something like Python.  For instance, if you wanted to process ten files in a batch, it'd absolutely be possible in a batch file, but almost trivial in a Python script.  Or, if you want to combine, say "10 minutes" of videos to one file, it's possible in Python, but nearly impossible in a batch file.

Comment: After more than one year, your code still works. Thank you very much !