# ffmpeg - Concat multi mp4 files with audio file not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711117/concat-multiple-video-and-audio-files-with-ffmpeg) to concat multi mp4 files with audio file. 
But its not success. Have a lots error notifications had been displayed. I dont know how to fix it. 
Below is my command:

```
"ffmpeg" -f concat -safe 0 \
-i /path/to/text.txt \
-i /path/to/audio.mp3 -vsync vfr -vf scale="640:640" -pix_fmt yuv420p \
/path/to/output.mp4 2>&1
```

The detail contents of `text.txt`

```
file '/path/to/file1.mp4'
file '/path/to/file2.mp4'
file '/path/to/file3.mp4'
file '/path/to/file4.mp4'
file '/path/to/file5.mp4'
file '/path/to/file6.mp4'
file '/path/to/file7.mp4'
file '/path/to/file8.mp4'
file '/path/to/file9.mp4'
file '/path/to/file10.mp4'
file '/path/to/file11.mp4'
file '/path/to/file12.mp4'
file '/path/to/file13.mp4'
file '/path/to/file14.mp4'
file '/path/to/file15.mp4'
file '/path/to/file16.mp4'
file '/path/to/file17.mp4'
file '/path/to/file18.mp4'
```

And some lines of output errors:

```
[concat @ 0x357e620] DTS 192000 < 229888 out of order
[h264 @ 0x36920e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x36920e0] error while decoding MB 32 0
[h264 @ 0x36920e0] concealing 2025 DC, 2025 AC, 2025 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x36b7a80] concealing 1449 DC, 1449 AC, 1449 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x36ff440] corrupted macroblock 26 1 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x36ff440] error while decoding MB 26 1
[h264 @ 0x36ff440] concealing 2003 DC, 2003 AC, 2003 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x371af40] concealing 1456 DC, 1456 AC, 1456 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x3736a40] ref 5 overflow
[h264 @ 0x3736a40] error while decoding MB 1 1
[h264 @ 0x3736a40] concealing 2025 DC, 2025 AC, 2025 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x3752520] concealing 1449 DC, 1449 AC, 1449 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x376dfa0] P sub_mb_type 8 out of range at 2 1
[h264 @ 0x376dfa0] error while decoding MB 2 1
[h264 @ 0x376dfa0] concealing 2025 DC, 2025 AC, 2025 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x37a55a0] ref 6 overflow
[h264 @ 0x37a55a0] error while decoding MB 3 1
[h264 @ 0x37a55a0] concealing 2025 DC, 2025 AC, 2025 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x3789aa0] concealing 1449 DC, 1449 AC, 1449 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x36b7a80] ref 5 overflow
[h264 @ 0x36b7a80] error while decoding MB 4 1
[h264 @ 0x36b7a80] concealing 2025 DC, 2025 AC, 2025 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x36920e0] concealing 1449 DC, 1449 AC, 1449 MV errors in P frame
```

Comment: have you tried simply concatenating the video files without adding the audio and rescaling `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/text.txt /path/to/output.mp4`  if the problem persist then try changing your input video file because there might be an issue  with the input

Comment: @Ahmed_Faraz yes, Its still occurs. May be inputs have different statistics. What stats I should set?

Comment: Same problem here. I'm concatenating 6 videos. The problem happens on playback on timestamp of video 4.