# Concat 50+ video files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have over 50 short video files, each 5 mins long which I want to concat.
Filenames are in the format: 20231222HHMMSS_300_S.mp4

I have looked at other similar queries here like:
[Concat multiple video and audio files with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711117/concat-multiple-video-and-audio-files-with-ffmpeg)

Wrote down the filenames in mergelist.txt, and it worked but writing down the filenames for 50+ videos is tedious.

Is there an quicker way to automatically read these filenames with similar format and merge them?

**Update** So I figured out that in Linux, doing `ls > filenames.txt`
copies all the filenames to a text file. But I still need to edit it so that it is in this format: `file 'filename.mp4'`
Please push me through the finish line here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
ls | sed -e "s/^/file '/" -e "s/$/'/" > filelist.txt
```

That says... *"pipe the output of `ls` through `sed` (the stream editor) and execute two operations on the stream, i.e. `sed -e OPERATION1 -e OPERATION2`. In the first operation, substitute the start of line (^) with `file '`. In the second operation, substitute the end of line ($) with a single quote."*