# How do I blur a segment in a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am looking through the docs for ffmpeg and am having a hard time finding my way around.

Is there a way to add blurring to a video for a specific range in the video.

Example: a 1 minute video. I want to blur seconds 30-35.

Is this possible and if so what does the command look like?

Comment: I believe ffmpeg has blur filter, but you would have to 3 slice the video first, process the slice you want to blur, and then join the video again.

Comment: I provide an answer using ffmpeg and boxtblur filter with timeline support in [How to blur a short scene in a video?](http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/8293/1760).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to do this with just single `ffmpeg` command, but with bash function You can do this with function:

```bash
function blurPartOfVideo {
    if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: blurPartOfVideo <videoName> <blurStartSeconds> <blurEndSeconds>"
        return 1
    fi

    videoName=$1
    blurStartSeconds=$2
    blurEndSeconds=$3
    
    blurValue=5 # the greater value the stronger blur is

    videoExtension="${videoName##*.}" # Get video extension from the filename

    videoNamePartBeforeBlur="$(basename "$videoName" ."$videoExtension")_until$blurStartSeconds.$videoExtension"
    videoNamePartToBlur="$(basename "$videoName" ."$videoExtension")_$blurStartSeconds-$blurEndSeconds.$videoExtension"
    videoNamePartAfterBlur="$(basename "$videoName" ."$videoExtension")_from$blurEndSeconds.$videoExtension"
    
    videoNamePartiallyBlurred="$(basename "$videoName" ."$videoExtension")_blurred.$videoExtension"
    
    echo "Trying to add blurring=$blurValue to video $videoName in time range: $blurStartSeconds - $blurEndSeconds, result video: $videoNamePartiallyBlurred"

    echo "Splitting video: $videoName -> $videoNamePartBeforeBlur, $videoNamePartToBlur, $videoNamePartAfterBlur"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$videoName" -t "$blurStartSeconds" "$videoNamePartBeforeBlur"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$videoName" -ss "$blurStartSeconds" -t "$(($blurEndSeconds - $blurStartSeconds))" "$videoNamePartToBlur"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$videoName" -ss "$blurEndSeconds" "$videoNamePartAfterBlur"
    
    videoNamePartToBlur_blurred="$(basename $videoNamePartToBlur)_blurred.$videoExtension"
    echo "Adding blur to video: $videoNamePartToBlur, blurValue=$blurValue, creating file: $videoNamePartToBlur_blurred"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$videoNamePartToBlur" -vf "boxblur=$blurValue" "$videoNamePartToBlur_blurred"

    echo "Merging files: $videoNamePartBeforeBlur + $videoNamePartToBlur_blurred + $videoNamePartAfterBlur = $videoNamePartiallyBlurred"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i $videoNamePartBeforeBlur -i $videoNamePartToBlur_blurred -i $videoNamePartAfterBlur \
        -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
        -map "[v]" -map "[a]" $videoNamePartiallyBlurred

    echo "Video partially blurred: $videoNamePartiallyBlurred in time range: $blurStartSeconds - $blurEndSeconds [seconds]"
    
    # removing remporaly files:
    # rm $videoNamePartBeforeBlur $videoNamePartToBlur_blurred $videoNamePartAfterBlur $videoNamePartToBlur_blurred
}
```

Usage:

```bash
blurPartOfVideo fileToBlur.MOV 10 15
```

**Note:** that there are [more ways of merging files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg), some of them can be more effective for specific file extension.