# how to merge the mp4 videos using mp4parser which are taken from both front and back camera alternatively

Tags: merge, rotation, mp4parser

i am developing an app to merge the  n number of videos using mp4parser.The videos which are to be merged are taken in both front camera and back camera. if i merge these videos into single , it is merging all videos  fine, but the alternative videos which are taken via front camera are merged as inverted.
what can i do.
please any one help me.

this is my code to merge videos:

```
try {


String f1,f2,f3;


f1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/testvideo1.mp4";// video took via back camera


f2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/testvideo2.mp4";// video took via front camera


f3 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/testvideo3.mp4";// video took via front camera


        Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[] {
          MovieCreator.build(f1),
          MovieCreator.build(f2),
          MovieCreator.build(f3) 
         };
            List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
            List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
            for (Movie m : inMovies) {
                for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(t);
                    }
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                        videoTracks.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            Movie result = new Movie();
            if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            }
            if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
            }
            BasicContainer out =  (BasicContainer) new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
            WritableByteChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(
            String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/CombinedVideo.mp4"), "rw").getChannel();
            out.writeContainer(fc);                  
            fc.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Rvg", "exeption" + e);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Grace Venkat did you fixed that issue? If you fixed means please share your ideas. Me too facing same issue last three days. I will be really grateful to you. Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have this same problem, Can't seem to find a solution

Comment: Please share this idea same problem from my side.

Comment: I am also getting this problem. if you found any solution related this issue then please share your solution.

Comment: Hi Grace i tried above code but it shows file not found exception even i m getting video path properly can u plz share code.

Comment: I am facing same issue please suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

This is caused due to an orientation issue explained [here](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/issues/130). In short, it means that because of the different rotation metadata of videos recorded with the front camera and the back camera, when merging the videos using mp4parser every second video will be upside down.

**How to solve this issue:**

I have managed to solve this issue in a two different ways.

**1. Re-encoding video** - using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) I managed to merge the videos in the correct orientation.

[How to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg), and my suggestion for [using FFmpeg in Android](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)

**Cons:**

The main problem with this solution is that it requires re-encoding the videos into the merged video, and this process can take a pretty long time.

Also this method is lossy due to the re-encoding

**Pro:**

This method can work regardless even if the videos resolution, frame rate, and bitrate are not the same.

**2. Using mp4parser/demuxer method** - in order to use mp4parser or FFmpeg demuxer method to merge the videos in the correct orientation, the videos must be provided with the same orientation - or with no rotation metadata. Using [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) `takeVideoSnapshot()` allows to record a video with no rotation metadata, so when merging it with mp4parser it is oriented correctly.

**Con:**

The main problem with this solution is that for the output to be with correct orientation and not fail, the input videos must have the same resolution, frame rate, bit rate and also rotation metadata(for correct orientation).

**Pros:**

This method requires no re-encoding so it is very very fast.

Also it is lossless.