# merge video files with ffmpeg

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I want to merge video files with same format with ffmpeg c#.
I want to merge two or three .mov files or .flv or any video filse.

I tried below code but its is not working.

```
strMergeVideo = "-i concat:\""+pathToFiles+"1.mov\\|"+pathToFiles+"1.mov\" -c copy \"" + pathOut + "output.mp4\"";
```

or

```
strMergeVideo = " -i \"" + pathToFiles + "1.mov\" -i \"" + pathToFiles + "1.mov\" -filter_complex \"[0:1] [0:0] [1:1] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" \""+pathOut+"1.mp4\"";
```

so please help me to achieve this.

Comment: I found the answer     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg