# Merging Video Files with PHP

Tags: php, file, video, merge

I have two mp4 files and i want to merge them.

```
$media1 = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/media1.mp4');
$media2 = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/media2.mp4');

file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/combined.mp4', $media1.$media2);
```

media1.mp4 : 1 Megabyte, 10 second

media2.mp4 : 2 Megabyte, 20 second

combined.mp4 : 3 Megabyte but 10 second (There is only media1.mp4)

How can i merge these two files?

Comment: Have you tried `php-ffmpeg`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two mp4 videos with the help of FFMPEG and PHP code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993756/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-videos-with-the-help-of-ffmpeg-and-php-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish you could combine encoded video stream with `$media1.$media2` but sadly, **you can't like that.**

Fortunately for you, php come with a `exec()` function, and using that with the little [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) program let you do that.

So what you have to do is to do a php `exec()` with ffmpeg and do the merge there.

Good luck !