# In yii2 merge two video file

Tags: video, yii2

in yii2 rest api.. i want to merge two video files? how to done it . i am using

```
$media2 = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/media2.mp4');
```

file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/combined.mp4', $media1.$media2);

but it cant worked

Comment: i think this is not possible to using file_put_contents.please use https://ffmpeg.org/ or other libraries for merge two video files

Comment: without ffmpeg it can not possible?

Comment: you can use ffmpeg or other liabraries.php functions not working for video merging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Video Files with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940139/merging-video-files-with-php)