# How to properly merge streamed video files into a single .mp4 files using PHP

Tags: php

After I recorded and saved streamed video files, it was saved in the following formats **.ts** and **.m3u8** file extension names

In the folder called `video` I have the following files:

```
video/chunk_0.ts
video/chunk_1.ts
video/chunk_2.ts
video/content.m3u8
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

How do I merge all these files in video folder into **.mp4** video file formats?

I have researched on Stack Overflow on how to do that, the [Stack Overflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940139/merging-video-files-with-php) suggest using **exec** and **ffmpeg**.

I guess something like the code below but they are other files in the folder:

```
<?php

$vi = exec(ffmpeg -i video/chunk_0.ts output.mp4);
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just try some commands on the console first. Maybe list them in order, separated by spaces, before the output file.

Answer (score 0):

as .m3u8 contains all segment information of .ts, you can directly transfer .m3u8 file to .mp4 using ffmpeg and shall merge all .ts files together

$vi = exec(ffmpeg -i video/content.m3u8 output.mp4);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).