# Make separate videos appear to be one video with VideoJS

Tags: html, video, video.js

I have a few videos which are each about 5 minutes in length. Is there any way to use VideoJS such that these five videos appear to be all one video, each concatenated one after the other?  The video length should appear to be the total length of all my videos. If I seek to a spot it should go to the corresponding video and play at the corresponding place. If VideoJS does not support this I would be happy to choose a different player.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to concatenate those two videos into one before trying to stream them.

You can try to use ffmpeg to concatenate them. See: [Concatenate two mp4 files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg), then you can stream the o/p video file by videoJS

Comment: I'd rather not do that due to copyright issues. The videos would not be hosted on my server, rather, I'm taking them from an outside source.

Comment: That is  not really a useful answer, @umopaplsdn is specifically asking on how to make a playlist seem like a unique video.