# How to concatenate .webm files and convert the resulting video to .mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'v tried many methods nothing is working for example

```
ffmpeg -i A.mov -i B.mov -i C.mov -i D.mov -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] [3:0] [3:1] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

ffmpeg -i "concat:A.webm | B.webm | C.webm | D.webm" -c copy output.mp4

ffmpeg -i 1.webm -i 2.webm -i 3.webm -i 4.webm -i 5.webm -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] [3:0] [3:1] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Always I find these errors or warning

```
[libvo_aacenc @ 04091820] Queue input is backward in time

Last message repeated 4 times

[mp4 @ 0408f0c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 770, current: 768; changing to 771.

[libvo_aacenc @ 04091820] Queue input is backward in time

[mp4 @ 0408f0c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 771, current: 768; changing to 772.

[libvo_aacenc @ 04091820] Queue input is backward in time

[mp4 @ 0408f0c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 772, current: 768; changing to 773.
[libvo_aacenc @ 04091820] Queue input is backward in time

[mp4 @ 0408f0c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 773, current: 768; changing to 774.

[mp4 @ 0408f0c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 774, current: 768; changing to 775.
[libvo_aacenc @ 04091820] Queue input is backward in time
```

Is there any way to do it or Its not possible....???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg/11175851#11175851 may be interesting to you