# How to encode(compress) video like youtube does?

Tags: video, encode

Is there any compressor/encoder, that encodes video exactly in same format as youtube does?

All I wanted to achieve, is that my video (converted to exactly same format as Youtube video (mp4/AVC 10/MPEG 4)  with my typical converter software)  to merge seamlessly with youtube-video (without re-encoding, without NON-LINEAR EDITORS, like MKVTOOLBOX)...

Although formats are same, yt video is only seems natively merge-able with another yt-videos, not the videos from my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to concatenate the video files.

There are some excellent posts on concatenating with ffmpeg as I am sure you are aware, for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/334402

And there is also good ffmpeg documentation on concatenation explain when you need to encode and when you don't, again as I am guessing you have already seen:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

For your case, because you want to avoid any encoding or decoding, you are limited in the types of video you can concatenate. For example, from the ffmpeg documentation:

> There are two methods within ffmpeg that can be used to concatenate files of the same type: the concat ''demuxer'' and the concat ''protocol''. The demuxer is more flexible - it requires the same codecs, but different container formats can be used; and it can be used with any container formats, while the protocol only works with a select few containers. However, the concat protocol is available in older versions of ffmpeg, where the demuxer isn't. The demuxer also requires that the inputs have a consistent bitrate setting, the concat protocol is more flexible in this regard.

The problem you are going to face is that there is no single format for YouTube videos when you get to this level of detail - for example even a single video that you view on YouTube will generally these days be available in different bit rates to match your current network conditions.

Similarly, different videos may have different frame rates, etc.

If you really have to avoid encoding at the concatenation stage you may find yourself having to interrogate the YouTube video you want to merge with, and then adjusting your video file to match it on a case by case basis (which may involved encoding anyway).

Comment: I like the last sentence much, but please explain: how to adjust my video file to match it on a case by case?

Comment: Actually, you probably won't like it when I explain it better! The 'adjusting' part may require encoding depending on the video. If you look at the ffmpeg link and some of your videos you may get a feel. For example if you want to use demux you may need to change the bitrate of your video. Unfortunately, working with videos is often processing expensive.