# Cut multiple videos and merge with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How can I cut a video into multiple parts and then join them together to make a new video with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You question is quiet general...
The following example may help you, but it might not solve your specific issues.

The example applies three stages:

- Create synthetic video (with no audio):

  ```
  ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=3:size=160x120:rate=10 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 testsrc.avi
  ```

  (The created video is uncompressed).
  Reference: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide
- Cut video into 3 parts (creating 3 video files):

  ```
  ffmpeg -i testsrc.avi -ss 00:00:00 -c copy -t 00:00:01 sec0.avi
  ffmpeg -i testsrc.avi -ss 00:00:01 -c copy -t 00:00:01 sec1.avi
  ffmpeg -i testsrc.avi -ss 00:00:02 -c copy -t 00:00:01 sec2.avi
  ```

  Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video
- Concatenate (merge) 3 parts in reverse order:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i "concat:sec2.avi|sec1.avi|sec0.avi" -codec copy output.avi
  ```

  Note: for Linux use single quotes `'`
  Reference: [Concatenate two mp4 files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

Synthetic video looks as the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 16):

You can use the concat demuxer.

**#1** Create a text file

```
file video.mp4
inpoint 34.5
outpoint 55.1
file video.mp4
inpoint 111.0
outpoint 155.3
file video.mp4
inpoint 278
outpoint 316.4
```

The inpoint/outpoint directives specify the trim in and out points in seconds for the file listed above them.

**#2a** Create the joint file

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt combined.mp4
```

---

**#2b** Do the overlay together

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -i background.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=400:400[v1];[1:v][v1]overlay=0:0:shortest=1" -shortest -preset superfast "output.mp4"
```

**External Audio stream with concat**

```
ffmpeg -i 12m.mp4 -f concat -i list.txt -vf setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.1 -af atempo=1.1 -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest new.mp4
```

Comment: after run commands *** ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt combined.mp4 ***
then  i want to run commands  *** ffmpeg -i combined.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=400:400 [v1], [1:v][v1]overlay=0:0" -shortest -preset superfast "output.mp4" *** || Let two lines of code run in a .bat directory
What should I do to connect those two lines together?
thank for help

Comment: When i run command #2b : errror command: option loop not found.
After run commands *** ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt combined.mp4 *** then i want to run commands *** ffmpeg -i 12m.mp4 -i combined.mp4 -vf setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.1 -af atempo=1.1 -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest new.mp4 *** || Let two lines of code run in a .bat directory What should I do to connect those two lines together?

Comment: Corrected cmd and added new one.

Comment: hello Mulvya when i creat list.txt if each video in other folder ( ex: D:\video1 and D:\video2) What should I do? example text list: 

file D:\video1\videoa
inpoint 34.5
outpoint 55.1

file D:\video1\videob
inpoint 278
outpoint 316.4

Comment: Add `-safe 0` before `-i` on the cmd line.

Comment: i have 10 video in folder
, I want to livestream on youtube loop that 10 video (24/7)
Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is #2b for? I tried #2a to splice together parts of an .flv file, and it works... but the video quality noticeable degrades. Is there a better way? Probably recoding is necessary?

Comment: @StefanReich see comment above by OP at `Mar 14 '17 at 5:28`. If you're saving to FLV, add `-c:v libx264`. If that encoder is already chosen, add `-crf 18`.

Comment: @Gyan I am using the above method but with a single video file and just using multiple inpoints and outpoints.  I need both audio and video and I am finding the audio is off.  Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming into this, I noticed that Gyan's answer has the drawback that inpoints and outpoints are approximate in the case of inter-frame codecs (see the [doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)).

The following command (from [Ilogan's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61642)) does not have this drawback. It works both for one or multiple inputs.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 \ 
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=3.48:5.72,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [0:v]trim=6.56:8.68,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0b]; \
 [1:v]trim=13.52:15.36,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [1:v]trim=17.56:23.32,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1b]; \
 [2:v]trim=20.6:23.96,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [v0][v0b][v1][v1b][v2]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[v]" \
-map "[v]" -an -crf 17 output.mp4
```

Comment: The drawback of your solution is that the video needs to be re-encoded which may be okay for some uses cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Update 2023-12-26]
I used the answer "#2a Create the joint file" by @Gyan but the output video had very low quality by default. By reading the command output I realized that the input bit rate was 1170 kb/s while the output had been set automatically to 200 kb/s. I added the modifier `-c:v copy -c:a copy` before the output file name and it worked as I wanted. Please note that, in my case, I used only one input video file so there was no codec or video format mismatch.

The list.txt file looked like this:

```
file input.avi
inpoint 1.5
outpoint 11.1
file input.avi
inpoint 14.5
outpoint 16.5
file input.avi
inpoint 19.5
outpoint 25.2
file input.avi
inpoint 27.5
outpoint 36
```

The command line looked like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt  -c:v copy -c:a copy output.avi
```

I also got a lot of warnings, but the final result was good. The warnings said something like:

```
[avi @ 0x5647508c6700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1774, current: 1640; changing to 1775. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```