# Cut one video in multiples pieces and merge it

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-conversion

I have an `in.mkv` video with one video track, two audio tracks and two subtitles tracks, and I want to obtain an `out.mp4` video with one video track, one audio track and one subtitle track.

Also, the `out.mkv` must only contain:

- from second 107.72 to 111.28 of `in.mkv`
- from second 119.04 to 162.04 of `in.mkv`
- from second 225.04 to 260.72 of `in.mkv`
- from second 262.44 to 264.8 of `in.mkv`
- from second 264.84 to 284.96 of `in.mkv`
- from second 320.6 to 325.52 of `in.mkv`
- from second 358.12 to 392.24 of `in.mkv`
- from second 617.68 to 945.96 of `in.mkv`
- from second 946.0 to 950.96 of `in.mkv`

I have tried it:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 107.72 -to 111.28 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p00.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 119.04 -to 162.04 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p01.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 225.04 -to 260.72 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p02.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 262.44 -to 264.8  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p03.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 264.84 -to 284.96 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p04.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 320.6  -to 325.52 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p05.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 358.12 -to 392.24 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p06.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 617.68 -to 945.96 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p07.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 946.0  -to 950.96 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -c:s mov_text p08.mp4
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error -i 'concat:p00.mp4|p01.mp4|p02.mp4|p03.mp4|p04.mp4|p05.mp4|p06.mp4|p07.mp4|p08.mp4' -c copy out.mp4
```

But It isn't cutting `in.mkv` in the exact second that I set in `-ss` and `-to` parameter.

How can select with precision some parts of a video in order to obtain just one output with these parts joined?

Thanks.

Comment: How non-exact second are they? Also, what is the frame rate of your video?

Comment: It is not recommended to create small video pieces and concatenate them. Try following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750147/4926757).