# Merging separate video files into one - resulting file size

Tags: video

Let's say I have multiple video files.
Video1.mp4 - 2GB
Video2.mp4 - 3GB
Video3.mp4 - 1GB
Video4.mp4 - 4GB
Their size sum is 2+3+1+4 = 10GB.

All those videos are camera videos from car camera.

And I want to merge them into one file. **Will the merged file size be equal to the sum of sizes of source videos, or will it be greater, or will it be lesser?**

I do not change the videos compression method during merge.

I suspect that the merged video size will be lesser than the sum of sizes of source videos because of how the compression works, but my friend arques, and I want you to explain us who is right....

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if nothing else changes and there is nothing odd about your mp4 files, then size would be less as the mp4 container format includes headers and metadata information and you should end up with less of this in the single video.

However.... best thing is to try - this answer has an example one line ffmpeg command you use to experiment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22688066/334402