# Merge two audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to merge Two mp3 file using ffmpeg library.but not succsesfull.Following is my code

```
GeneralUtils.checkForPermissionsMAndAbove(MergerActivity.this, true);
LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
try {
    String workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    //String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4"};
    String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg -i \"concat: /storage/internalsd/Music/02 Love Dose.mp3| /storage/internalsd/Music/02 Love Dose.mp3\" -acodec copy output.mp3"};

    vk.run(complexCommand , workFolder , getApplicationContext());
    Log.i("test", "ffmpeg4android finished successfully");
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Log.e("test", "vk run exception.", e);
}
```

The error log display following

```
vk run exception.

com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.CommandValidationException
    at com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI.run(LoadJNI.java:39)
    at com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI.run(LoadJNI.java:55)
    at com.handyaudio.MergerActivity.onMergeButtonClicked(MergerActivity.java:356)
    at com.handyaudio.MergerActivity.onClick(MergerActivity.java:272)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
```

Please help to solve error.

Comment: Use the [concat demuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/1109017), not the concat protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **permissions** first.

Try this out -

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "amovie=file1.mp3 [a0]; amovie=file2.mp3 [a1]; [a0][a1] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest [aout]" -map [aout] -acodec mp3 file_merged.mp3
```

**Edit 1 :**

The concat protocol is this : `ffmpeg -i 'concat:input1|input2 -codec copy output`

I think where you are going wrong is that in your file names, you put a `space` before completing the file name, i.e, `02 LoveDose.mp3`

Comment: It appears the OP wants to concatenate, not mix. Also, no need for `amovie`, just add inputs as usual `ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 ...`.