# How could I concatenate 3 videos in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using FFMPEG already for 2 videos and working fine with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i outro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

but now I want to concatenate 3 videos or more how could I do that?

Comment: Use the [concat demuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg) instead of the concat protocol and you will avoid the extra re-muxing steps.