# FFMPEG: Combine two H264 FIFO into MP4 File

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am combining two H264 into one MP4 file using following command,

```
ffmpeg -r <framerate> -i <input_fifo_1> -r <framerate_2> -i <input_fifo_2> -c copy -t 20 output.mp4
```

After execution of command, If I play the MP4 file using following command,

```
ffplay output.mp4 -vst 0     // TO Play Track 1
ffplay output.mp4 -vst 1     // TO Play Track 2
```

Second Video Track of MP4 have some minor glitch in video.

To figure it out whether FIFO data has issues, I reversed the fifo input in ffmpeg command. But still I am getting minor glitch in Second Video Track only.

Any Pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg  not quite your format but may be worth reviewing

Comment: I am not merging or concating the file. But I am copying into different stream of single MP4 file

Comment: Share full log of the conversion command.

Comment: What kind of glitch? how does it look?

Comment: Frame Missing for 1 or 2 seconds.