# How to use ffmpeg to merge multiple .mp4 files? (same encoder, simple merge will work)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying:

- [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1059245/ffmpeg-join-two-mp4-files-with-ffmpeg-on-command-line

---

#### Option A:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output`

> Line 1: unknown keyword 'file'
>   list.txt: Invalid data found when processing input

`cat list.txt
file './001-eclipse.mp4'
file './002-sundown.mp4'
file './003-robothear.mp4'
file './004-NOPE-boring-tower.mp4'`

#### Option B:

`ffmpeg -i "concat:001-eclipse.mp4|002-sundown.mp4|003-robothear.mp4|004-NOPE-boring-tower.mp4" -c copy output.mp4`

`ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7feb1d001200] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it
    Last message repeated 2 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'concat:001-eclipse.mp4|002-sundown.mp4|003-robothear.mp4|004-NOPE-boring-tower.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  Duration: 00:00:13.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 161885 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 5376x2688, 54015 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 5376x2688, q=2-31, 54015 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  341 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   89943kB time=00:00:13.52 bitrate=54497.5kbits/s speed=90.2x
video:89937kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.005972%`

It contains only the first video :/

---

#### Any ideas?

My version on Mac:

`ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100`

Comment: give absolute paths

Comment: @FlashThunder keyword `file` still unknown: https://imgur.com/a/UFKrPkX

Comment: remove the BOM from txt file

Comment: Found workaround: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/337246-how-to-join-files-in-Avidemux

Answer (score 1):

It did work for me. I'm using Windows 10.

I've used this as a source [https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate].

All my `mp4` files and `list.txt` were in the same folder.

My `list.txt` file is:

```
file '20190710_141637.mp4'
file '20190710_144949.mp4'
file '20190710_153155.mp4'
file '20190710_160506.mp4'
```

then I run the command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

and the output was:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0650ce00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17259 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 17003 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-07-10T17:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-07-10T17:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 17003 kb/s, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-07-10T17:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-07-10T17:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0650ce00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filtereed=33.1x
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0650ce00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filterpeed=33.1x
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 065bf040] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filterpeed=29.6x
frame=208306 fps=922 q=-1.0 Lsize=14635199kB time=01:55:42.00 bitrate=17270.5kbits/s speed=30.7x
video:14409412kB audio:216937kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.060511%
```