# Flutter/Dart: Find two video segments and merge them into a single valid video file?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two video files on my iPhone. Is it possible, using Dart, to find two specific 10-second segments in each, and merge them both into a valid 20 second video file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so there's a FFMpeg plugin for flutter that allows you to do all of this.

https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg

Cutting a 15 second video segment starting at second 20:

```
ffmpeg -i Funny.mkv -ss 00:00:20 -codec copy -t 15  Funny_cut.mkv
```

Merging a list of videos that is stored in videos.txt:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy Funny_join.mkv
```

For more about FFMpeg:

https://www.poftut.com/ffmpeg-command-tutorial-examples-video-audio/

Comment: Hi there, where do you save these videos, @DataGrump?

Comment: The app’s documents folder. Search for the shared_preferences plugin. @hoangquyy

Comment: @hoangquyy sorry, getApplicationDocumentsDirectory in path_provider...not shared_preferences.

Comment: sorry, i mean in android not ios, thanks for your help.

Comment: @hoangquyy it maps to the correct directory based on your os. That’s the point. Why use Android specific code when you don’t have to?

Comment: Hi @DataGrump do you have issue with merge video? I can cut video but can't merge videos, what is the format of txt file? "a.mp4\nb.mp4", right?

Comment: @hoangquyy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Is there a way to do this in flutter web?