# How to play multiple sources with flutter plugin video_player

Tags: flutter, video-player

How  to play multiple sources with video_player?

I'm about mixing the video and audio source, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You only can merge them as a video but can not play them at a same time. If you want to merge it, try this: [Merge videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165137/flutter-dart-find-two-video-segments-and-merge-them-into-a-single-valid-video-f/56235274?noredirect=1#comment106879273_56235274)

It worked for me.

Comment: but if I merge this, I need to download video and audio, thanks anyway. I'll try downloading chunk by chunk

Answer (score 0):

```
 final List<VideoPlayerController> _playerControllers = [
   VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/video_0.mp4"),
   VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/video_1.mp4"),
   VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/video_2.mp4"),
 ];


for (var element in _playerControllers) {
  element.initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The video_player offers a crucial property mixWithOthers. Set it to true during video initialization:

```
videoController = VideoPlayerController.asset(
    'path/to/asset',
    videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true))
  ..initialize()
```

mixWithOthers might not work on all platforms (especially web). You might need to explore platform-specific solutions for web in such cases.