# How to merge two audio files with FFmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I've been trying to merge two audio tracks together. I want the shorter audio "**track.mp3**" to come first, then the longer audio **Wizkid** should come immediately after the **track.mp3**

Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i track.mp3 -i Wizkid.mp3 -filter_complex concat=n=1:v=0:a=1 fin.mp3
```

The code did merge both audio files, but it created an 11 second audio file. The track.mp3 is less than 5 seconds while the Wizkid.mp3 is about 04:11 long.

Any solution to merge both audio files with both audio lengths merged together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: Show full log from command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -i file2.mp3 -acodec copy test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1
```

I just did it and it appears to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks alot. It Worked perfectly 