# file concat mp4's using ffmpeg does not concat

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have 3 mp4's in my input text file(`a.txt`).

Contents of `a.txt`-

```
file '/Users/path-to-file/1.mp4'
file '/Users/path-to-file/2.mp4'
file '/Users/path-to-file/3.mp4'
```

The command I am executing (Referring to [Docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg/11175851)) -

```
ffmpeg -safe 0  -f concat -i a.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

The `output.mp4` is created. When I play the video `output.mp4`, I see the video & audio of 1.mp4 playing. But, after it completes, I just hear the audio of 2.mp4 and 3.mp4. **The video is stuck on the last frame of 1.mp4 during that time.**

Please can you tell me as to what I am missing?

---

**Update:**
The video plays only in quick-view of quicktime player. The video crashes VLC when I try to open in VLC. I think this suggests the encoding is not right or something else is wrong in the above steps.

Comment: A quick check - for this command the mp4 must be the same type, i.e. from the documentation above 'All files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc.).' I've seen It give unpredictable results when this is not the case.

Comment: If your videos are from different sources (eg: not same camera) then you'll just have to drop that `-c copy` which will encode an output of the combined videos.