# FFMPEG with moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, gpu, cpu, moviepy

I'm working on something that concatenate videos and adds some titles on through moviepy.

As I saw on the web and on my on pc moviepy works on the CPU and takes a lot of time to save(render) a movie. Is there a way to improve the speed by running the writing of moviepy on GPU? Like using FFmpeg or something like this?

I didn't find an answer to that on the web, so I hope that some of you can help me.
I tried using `thread=4` and `thread=16` but they are still very very slow and didn't change much.

My CPU is very strong (i7 10700k), but still, rendering on moviepy takes me for a compilation with a total of 8 minutes 40 seconds, which is a lot.

Any ideas?Thanks!
the code doesnt realy matter but :

```
def Edit_Clips(self):

    clips = []

    time=0.0
    for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(self.path)):
        if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
            tempVideo=VideoFileClip(self.path + "\\" + filename)

            txt = TextClip(txt=self.arrNames[i], font='Amiri-regular',
                           color='white', fontsize=70)
            txt_col = txt.on_color(size=(tempVideo.w + txt.w, txt.h - 10),
                                   color=(0, 0, 0), pos=(6, 'center'), col_opacity=0.6)

            w, h = moviesize = tempVideo.size
            txt_mov = txt_col.set_pos(lambda t: (max(w / 30, int(w - 0.5 * w * t)),
                                                 max(5 * h / 6, int(100 * t))))

            sub=txt_mov.subclip(time,time+4)
            time = time + tempVideo.duration

            final=CompositeVideoClip([tempVideo,sub])

            clips.append(final)

    video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
    print("after")
    video.write_videofile(self.targetPath+"\\"+'test.mp4',threads=16,audio_fps=44100,codec = 'libx264')
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Posted a code jakub

Comment: I see `os.listdir()` - how many files .mp4 do you have in file? Maybe you should use `subprocess` to runs many files at the same time ?

Comment: i have between 15-25

Comment: i use it so i can take all the videos from a directory but i dont run them at the same time i concatnate them

Comment: High quality-per-bitrate video encoding is *very* CPU intensive, especially x265; but  x264 `-preset slower` is fairly usable.  That's pretty much unavoidable, unless you want to consider lower video-quality options like hardware encoders built in to your GPU.  (These days they might not be too bad, especially if you don't mind throwing lots of bitrate at it, but if you want to archive your results, quality-per-bitrate is important for disk space.  If you're going to upload to youtube or something, they'll transcode anyway so use plenty of bitrate for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the past I was same problem and I solved that.

You need to use this command in your code ONLY one time.

`video = CompositeVideoClip([clip1, clip2, clip3])`

and export the video:

`video.write_videofile(path_final_video)`

while the video is export, moviepy will use all your cores.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: It worked for me, well done

Answer (score 6):

I was able to significantly speed things up by trying different encoders.

You can type in the following command to get a list on your system:

```
ffmpeg -encoders
```

Then you can try each codec to see which one gives you the best result:

```
final.write_videofile(
        filename,
        threads=5,
        bitrate="2000k",
        audio_codec="aac",
        codec="h264_videotoolbox",
    )
```

For me `h264_videotoolbox` worked the best, but your system may be different. To my understanding you would have `h264_nvenc` if you were on an nvidia system.

Comment: Is it possible to write video using ffmpeg command by passing VideoFileClip as input?

Answer (score 4):

I am using a GTX3070 on Windows and the `h264_nvenc` codec allowed me to use my GPU.
`clip.write_videofile(video_file, codec='h264_nvenc')`

Answer (score 0):

My gpu type is nvida, and I got 10 times faster with this command.
you can try this:

`echo y|ffmpeg -r 25 -i "a.mkv" -vcodec h264_nvenc  "b.mp4"`

If that not work, you can try else gpu accelerators:

```
-vcodec [accelerator_type]
# h264_nvenc
# hevc
# hevc_nvenc
# libx265
```

Run call in python(win 10):

```
input = 'a.mkv'
output = 'b.mp4'

call = "echo y|ffmpeg -r 25 -i \"%s\" -vcodec h264_nvenc  \"%s\"" % (input, output)
call

import os
os.system(call)

# subprocess.call or os.popen can get the call's return, 
# but if you want get the return at the same time,
# you should use this way:
import subprocess
pi= subprocess.Popen(call,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in iter(pi.stdout.readline,'b'):
    print(i)
```

But this way is not work on moviepy's concat function because it's not support GPU.
u'd better use ffmpeg to connact clips.

```
# concat_ffmpeg.bat
echo y|ffmpeg -i 1.mkv  -qscale 4 1.mpg
echo y|ffmpeg -i 2.mkv  -qscale 4 2.mpg
echo y|ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mpg|2.mpg" -c copy output.mp4

## sometimes can't use the [-c copy], u can try this and use GPU: 
# echo y|ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mpg|2.mpg" -vcodec h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

or
[`Concatenating media files`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

## Reference:

[`How can I speed up moviepy by gpu? #923`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/923)

[`ffmpeg 4.0 NVIDIA NVDEC-accelerated Support ? #790`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/790)

Comment: but where do i add it ? because i run my program like "python main.py" so where do i add this command

Comment: you can use the `call = 'command'`, then `import os; os.system(call)`

Comment: Why would you transcode both `.mkv` files to MPEG-2 / MPEG-1 `.mpg`?  That's an ancient codec much worse than x264 or other h.264 encoders, let alone h.265 or VP9.  FFmpeg can concat two different input files to a single encode into a `.mp4` or `.mkv`.  [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232) shows how, including with inputs where the inputs are different formats or even resolutions and need rescaling or filtering.  You can use that with a standard `-c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a libopus -b:a 80k output.mkv` to get good quality-per-bitrate.

Comment: re: quality per bitrate: see [Why does preset "veryfast" in FFmpeg generate the most compressed file compared to all other presets?](https://superuser.com/a/1557090)

Answer (score 0):

contrary to the comments, it is the fastest for me

```
write_videofile(result_path, bitrate=bitrate, threads=64, verbose=False, preset='ultrafast', ffmpeg_params=['-loglevel', 'panic'], codec="libx264")
```

It happened. I think my processor is much better than my video card.
[render speed img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4POTp.png)

In this way, I was able to get up to 125-130 while rendering.

Comment: Never use `ultrafast` except with lossless encodes; the quality is terrible, like noticeable blocking artifacts even when you let it use plenty of bitrate like crf=18.  `preset='superfast'` is the fastest you should consider using, but you can get significantly better quality-per-bitrate with presets like `medium` or `slower`, at the cost of more CPU time.  Presets like `faster` or `fast` are worth considering if you need to trade away compression efficiency (quality-per-bitrate) for speed.

Comment: CPU vs. GPU speed depends on your CPU (many cores with AVX2 or AVX-512) vs. how fast your hardware encoder is.  You didn't specify what CPU or GPU you tested on or what resolution this 130 FPS was with.