# What I'm doing wrong in my code , How to merge 2 videos with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I realize that this command exports the first video that has only 30 seconds and the second video has more minutes but It only exports the first video without merging the second video, what I'm doing wrong? I suspect that the command is wrong. Please help.

By the way, I'm using windows 10 .

Is another way to merge videos , let me know please and thanks.?

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:D:\MEGAVIDEOS\jej.mp4|D:\MEGAVIDEOS\video.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Updated: These are messages that appear when I run the command :

[messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd3k2.png)

[message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiL1C.png)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/188331)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: I've checked some commands from that post  but some of them  didn't work too. I've updated the post too.

Comment: None of those commands, they didn't work :(

Comment: Unfortunately, "didn't work" doesn't tell us much. Both inputs must have the same attributes for proper concatenation. Show the output of `ffmpeg -i jej.mp4 -i video.mp4` and I can give you a command you can copy and paste.